# Strategy/pattern for committing GWT CellTable changes to server

Tags: web-services, gwt, rest, gwt-rpc

I've got a GWT CellTable displaying data suppled from a server.  As per normal, the CellTable very closely matches the backend table.

I'm unsure on a strategy for server commits.  The FieldUpdater for my table expects to fire events when a single field has changed, so:

1. should I fire individual field updates to the backend?
2. should I queue up field commits until the user leaves that row, and then update all necessary fields in the backend?  (I could highlight un-saved changes in that row)
3. should I queue up row commits until the user presses 'Submit' at the foot of the page?  (I could highlight un-saved row changes across the whole table).

Strategy 1 seems to be the GWT way.  Strategies 2 & 3 incur reduced comms processing, although they need extra GWT scaffolding to be written.

Any thoughts?  Have I missed any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a thorough listing of the options.  I'd go with #1 by default - it's simpler to code, and the user gets faster feedback.  On the other hand, if you're in a situation like editing a document, where maybe the user wants a chance to compose a full response before part of it is visible to others, #2 or #3 might be most appropriate. #3 could get awkward to keep track of over multiple pages of your table.  Whatever you do, make sure you have a plan in mind for a failed request.

Comment: thanks (as ever) for the prompt reply Riley.  My target app is a Project Management-style app where there a list of deliverables with dates & % complete. The use-case I'd imagined was a user going in and correcting the % complete and finish date - I was wondering if 'received wisdom' was to focus on reducing backend comms, or streamline client procession.
thanks again - Ian.

Comment: Update: I've implemented the first option and it's working great.  The client side algorithm is straightforward, and because the database changes are so simple the performance is great.  Thanks again for the advice.